# Apache http client get encoding

Tags: java, rest, encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I do some simple get request via the latest apache httpclient.

When I do this get request via browser - encoding is OK.

But problem occurs when i'm trying to use httpclient:

```
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(fullUrl);
        get.setHeader("Accept-Encoding","UTF-8");
        get.setHeader("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
        get.setHeader("Content-Encoding","UTF-8");
        get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
...
        EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

and some [Umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(linguistics)) are not exists.

BTW, returns null:

```
     response.getEntity().getContentEncoding();
```

**Edit:**

The server returns these headers:

```
Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →3402
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Tue, 29 Nov 2016 10:49:30 GMT
Expires →Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)
X-Content-Type-Options →nosni
```

**Edit:**

Response:

In Java code:

```
 "items": [
    {
      "title": "KjÃ¸retÃ",
    },
....
```

In Chrome:

```
 "items": [
    {
      "title": "Kjøretøy,
    },
....
```

Comment: `Content-Encoding` and `Content-Type` are meaningless for a `GET` request. What `Content-Type` does the server *return*?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/da7T2uKy

Comment: 'some Umlauts are not exists'. Now please also add the relevant part of the response.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/Y0HXdyi2

Comment: What do you mean by 'In Java code'? Do you print the UTF-8 encoded reponse? How?